# VSCODE Hosted Blazor WASM project: Server debugging works. Client Debugging doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, linux, visual-studio-code, blazor-webassembly

I have been trying to fix this issue but have come up short. And I don't seem to have any luck looking for tutorials on doing **HOSTED** blazor wasm projects in dotnet that addresses my issue.

I'm using VSCODE. The issue is that I can debug the server side code just fine. But not the client side code. Despite there being two sessions in my call stack.

Here are the step I took to encountered this issue:

- Installed DotNet 6.
- I created a new project (Blazor Wasm Hosted) `dotnet new blazorwasm -ho -au Individual -p`.
- Installed Chrome
- Created a self Signed Certificate (and made Chrome accept it).
- Opened the project in VSCode installed the C# and BlazorWasm debugging extensions
- After VSCode created the task.json and launch.json files. I tweaked them to run from the server project and open in Chrome.
- Run/Debug my config to launch "hosted blazor wasm app"

**The problem is:**

- If I put a breakpoint in Server/WeatherForecastController.cs. The breakpoint will hit.
- If I put a breakpoint on Client/Pages/Counter.razor. The breakpoint doesn't hit. And when I mouse over the breakpoint it says: "***No symbols have been loaded for this document***".

Here is the project's github page: https://github.com/cyberyaga/TerritoryWeb

Here is my launch.json configuration:

```
        {
            "name": "Launch and Debug Hosted Blazor WebAssembly App",
            "type": "blazorwasm",
            "request": "launch",
            "hosted": true,
            "browser": "chrome",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Server/bin/Debug/net6.0/TerritoryWeb.Server.dll",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Server",
            "url": "https://localhost:7230"
        }
```

Here is my dotnet info:

```
dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.100
 Commit:    9e8b04bbff

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     manjaro
 OS Version:  
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         arch-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.0
  Commit:  4822e3c3aa

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.100 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I tried looking to see if I missed anything in my launch.json. But so far, I've not gotten Client side to hit. Despite there being two separate sessions in my call stack.

**UPDATE**

After doing some actual development on the project. I kind of have an idea as to what might be happening. If I debug in VSCODE (F5). I noticed that my "Client" project isn't getting built. I have to manually do a `dotnet build` or a `dotnet run` so that the client project gets updated. That might be why debugging doesn't work on the client. Seems like the source and compiled versions don't match.

**UPDATE #2**

So, I decided to test this on another distro. I tried doing this in Ubuntu 21.10... And both Server and Client debugging works as expected. Not sure what the issue is. I personally don't like Ubuntu as a distro, but I guess I will use it for the time being.

I would still like to know what's causing this, so that I can get it working in Manjaro.

Comment: Might be a config problem? I found a workaround is to use Edge instead, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72037574) for working config.

Comment: Well sir... I gave up on this project for a while, but I came back to this post to see if anyone had responded. I've got to say. I saw this comment with skepticism (thinking it might not work). Boy was I wrong. I installed edge browser and it worked like a charm. Thank you for the info.